# How can I do a Group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can do a lot of requests to a house, but only one request can be accepted. If the request is accepted, the request is saved in my San_Negocio table. In my table San_Proposta, I save teh request.

I want to do a query that get all data in san_proposta that has status equals 1, and all data in san_proposta that has all status equals 2 but in san_negocio, has the ValidaVenda different then ValidaCaptacao

**San_Proposta**

```
Proposta_Id    Imovel_Id    DataHora                Status
1              2001         2012-03-07 00:00:00     1
2              2001         2012-03-07 00:00:01     1
3              2001         2012-03-07 14:00:00     2
4              2001         2012-03-07 15:00:00     1
5              2002         2012-03-07 00:00:00     1
6              2002         2012-03-07 00:00:02     1
```

**San_Negocio**

```
Negocio_Id     Imovel_Id    Proposta_Id   ValidaVenda    ValidaCaptacao
1              2001         3             0              1
```

**What I Want**

```
Imovel_Id    Number Of Propost With status 1
2001         3
2002         2
```

I'm trying this query, but the problem is the return. The Imovel_Id is repeated because of my DataHora that are different in each Request (Proposta_Id).

```
SELECT p.Proposta_Id 
FROM San_Proposta p 
WHERE p.StatusProposta_Id = 1 

UNION 

SELECT p.Proposta_Id 
FROM San_Proposta p 
LEFT JOIN San_Negocio 
ON San_Negocio.Proposta_Id = p.Proposta_Id 
WHERE p.StatusProposta_Id = 2 
AND San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao <> San_Negocio.ValidaVenda
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test this, but it'll look something like this:

```
select Imovel_Id, count(*) as "Number Of Propost With status 1" 
FROM San_Proposta 
WHERE Imovel_Id=2001 and Status=1
GROUPBY Imovel_Id
```

For the update:

```
select Imovel_Id, count(*) as "Number Of Propost With status 1" 
FROM San_Proposta p LEFT OUTER JOIN San_Negocio n ON p.Imovel_Id=n.Imovel_Id
WHERE p.Status=1
GROUPBY Imovel_Id
```

You can then proceed to evaluate any other columns in your where clause by updating where:

WHERE p.Status=1 and p.StatusProposta_Id=2

THe syntax for the left outer join might be different for sqlServer

Comment: You actually don't need the join for this particular query :)

Comment: We need to join to check the count of Proposta_Ids

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sn.Imovel_Id,COUNT(sn.Proposta_Id) as Count_Proposta_status
FROM San_Proposta sp,San_Negocio sn
WHERE sp.Imovel_Id = sn.Imovel_Id
AND sp.Imovel_Id=2001
AND sp.Status = 1
AND sn.Proposta_Id is NOT NULL 
GROUP BY sn.Imovel_Id;
```

Comment: I can't inform the Imovel_Id, has to be something more dynamic

Comment: How can I put an order by with the DataHora field, without replicate the data ?